# XSLT complex copy

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to copy an XML file with a XSL sheet. By copying I want "anonymize" my XML file, taking some elements of the XML as a variable.

Base:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<root>
    <top>
        <nbpeople>2</nbpeople>
    </top>
    <people>
        <id>45</id>
        <name>MARTIN</name>
        <firstname>Jean</firstname>
        <xyx>
            <oo>BLABLA</oo>
            <cp>11222</cp>
        </xyx>
    </people>
    <people>
        <id>98</id>
        <name>DUPONT</name>
        <firstname>Yves</firstname>
        <xyx>
            <oo>POPOPO</oo>
            <cp>33450</cp>
        </xyx>
    </people>
</root>
```

result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<root>
    <top>
        <nbpeople>2</nbpeople>
    </top>
    <people>
        <id>45</id>
        <name>people 45</name>
        <!-- {xyx/cp + id} = 11222 + 45 = 11267 -->
        <firstname>Jean 11267</firstname>
        <xyx>
            <oo>BLABLA</oo>
            <!-- {id + 20000} = 45 + 20000 = 20045 -->
            <cp>20045</cp>
        </xyx>
    </people>
    <people>
        <id>98</id>
        <name>people 98</name>
        <!-- {xyx/cp + id} = 33450 + 98 = 11267 -->
        <firstname>Yves 33548</firstname>
        <xyx>
            <oo>POPOPO</oo>
            <!-- {id + 20000} = 98 + 20000 = 20098 -->
            <cp>20098</cp>
        </xyx>
    </people>
</root>
```

**My real XML file is obviously more complex.**

Edit:
I doesn't want an XSL like:

```html
<xsl:template match="people/name">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="../id" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('people ', $id)" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="people/firstname">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="../id" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(text(), $id)" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

OR

<xsl:template match="people/name">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('people ', ../id)" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="people/firstname">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(text(), ../id)" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I have a lot of processing to do and a complex file on several levels. It would be unmanageable.

Thank's

Comment: "*taking some elements of the XML as a variable*" That doesn't mean anything. Variables can be used during XSL transformation. When the transformation ends, variables cease to exist.

Comment: Can you please explain why don't want an XSLT like the one you have shown? Thanks.

Comment: I have a lot of processing to do and a complex file on several levels. It would be unmanageable.

Answer (score 0):

Once you learn XSLT, you will see that is is not actually complex. The first thing to start off with is the [XSLT Identity Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

On its own, it copies across everything as-is, which is your case would mean you are almost there! You just need a template for your "exception" case, which the `name` element, to create a new value instead. It would look like this

```
<xsl:template match="people/name">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('people ', ../id)" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

And that's it! Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="people/name">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('people ', ../id)" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can add other templates if you wanted to change any other fields, in a similar manner.

EDIT: If you wanted to make it a bit more generic, rather than have templates for each individual field, you could do something like this:

```
    <xsl:template match="people/*[not(self::id)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(), ' ', ../id)" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

This anonymises all fields under the `people` record, apart from the id

Comment: Thank's. But my file is more complex. I don't use a simple id for each fileds.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain the logic behind what you are trying to achieve, please? What rules are you trying to implement? For example, what does `{xyx/cp + id}` represent in your output? Thank you.

Comment: Thank's. Done. My question is just en example. My file is more complex